# Submit Button with multiple ID Inside Looping?(Shopping Cart)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to Create a Shoping Cart on PHp,

The Code is simple, When the customer  fill the QTY  and click button Add to cart, the code will save the PRoduct ID and Qty to a Cart Table. But the problem is that Form  inside the Looping. And How Can I Get ID and Qty only from The button that Customer Click.

The Program look like this

[image]

And The Script Like This

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST[ADD]))
        {
            $qty   = $_POST[QTY];
            $harga = $_POST[HARGA_ASLI]; 
            $id    = $_POST[ID];

            print_r($_POST);
        }

         $kolom = 3;

        $sql = "SELECT *,FORMAT(harga,0)AS harga_digit FROM item";

        $hasil = mysql_query($sql);
        echo "<form method=POST action=index.php>";
        echo "<table>
               <tr>";
              $i = 0;
              while($data=mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
              {
                 if($i >= $kolom)
                 {
                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                    $i = 0;
                 }          
                 $i++;
                 echo "<td align='center'><br><a href='detailBarang.php?ID=$data[ID]'><img src='$data[img]' width='200' height='150'/><br>$data[nama_produk]</a><br>
                         Rp. $data[harga_digit]<br> 
                         <input type='submit' name='ADD' id='ADD' value='Add to Cart'>
                         <input type='text' name='QTY' id='QTY' placeholder='Qty' /><br>
                         <input type='hidden' name='HARGA_ASLI' id='HARGA_ASLI' value='$data[harga]' /><br>
                         <input type='hidden' name='ID' id='ID' value='$data[ID]' />
                         <br></td>";


              }//end of while

        echo "<tr></table>";
        echo "</form>"; 

  ?>
```

If i fill the Qty and click Add to Cart, only the last Item can Post The Data.

How To Post The data Only for Customer Choose?

Im very Appreciated Your Answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's convert your MySQL to MySQLi. More explanation inside the comments /* */:

```
<?php   
        $connection=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","NameofYourDatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();

}

$res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM item");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

$nameofsubmitbutton=$row['ID'];

if(isset($_POST[$nameofsubmitbutton])){

$nameofproduct=$row['namaproduk'];
$nameofnumbersubmitted=$nameofsubmitbutton."number";
$quantity=$_POST[$nameofnumbersubmitted];

if(empty($quantity)){
echo "You wanted to buy a ".$nameofproduct."?<br>Type in a number so you can add it to your cart.";
}

else {
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO yourTable ('','') VALUES ('$quantity','$nameofproduct')");
echo "You bought ".$quantity." of ".$nameofproduct;
}

} /* END OF IF ISSET */

} /* END OF WHILE LOOP $RES */

$kolom = 3;

$hasil = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT *,FORMAT(harga,0) AS harga_digit FROM item"); /* YOU SURE WITH THIS QUERY? */

echo "<form method=POST action=''>"; /* SUBMIT ON ITSELF */
echo "<table><tr>";

$i = 0; /* THIS WOULD ALSO SET AS YOUR COUNTER */
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($hasil))
{

$id=$data['ID'];

if($i >= $kolom){

echo "</tr><tr>";
$i = 0;

} /* END OF IF $i >= $KOLOM */   

$i++;

echo "<td align='center'><br><a href='detailBarang.php?ID=$data[ID]'><img src='$data[img]' width='200' height='150'/><br>".$data[nama_produk]."</a><br>Rp. ".$data[harga_digit]."<br>"; /* IF TO ECHO VARIABLES, USE ".$variable." */

$numbername=$id."number";

echo "<input type='number' name='$numbername' id='QTY' placeholder='Qty' /><br>"; /* CHANGE YOUR INPUT TYPE TO NUMBER */

/* NO NEED FOR THE HIDDEN INPUT */

echo "<input type='submit' name='$id' id='ADD' value='Add to Cart'></td>"; /* CHANGE THE NAME OF SUBMIT BUTTON TO THE CORRESPONDING ID FROM YOUR TABLE */



} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

echo "<tr></table>";
echo "</form>"; 

?>
```

I tried it on my local computer. You should too.

Here's a sample screen shot.
[image]

Comment: I Ihave Try your Advice, but still not work. My Item Show but if I Fill the Qty and klik the add cart. It nothing happen. I use PHP on linux, Or Maybe I must Change The PHP setting to convert mysql to mysqli?

Comment: My post is working. You should just double check your work. No need to change settings.

Comment: Hei, its Work. Thanks A Lot, The Problem is only the different of variable Thanks

Comment: See! You just need to check thoroughly. To improve more your shopping cart system, you should add some session on it and later on, some AJAX. Good luck with your work!

Comment: Of Course, Im nubie on PHP and after the Script Work I still learn how the Script Work. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This may do the trick:

```
<?php
  $kolom = 3;

  $sql = "SELECT *,FORMAT(harga,0)AS harga_digit FROM item";

  $hasil = mysql_query($sql);
  
  while($data=mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
  {
    if(isset($_POST['ADD'.$data[ID]]))
    {
        $qty   = $_POST['QTY'.$data[ID]];
        $harga = $_POST['HARGA_ASLI'.$data[ID]]; 
        $id    = $_POST['ID'.$data[ID]];

        print_r($_POST);
    }
  }
  echo "<form method=POST action=index.php>";
  echo "<table>
         <tr>";
        $i = 0;
        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
        {
           if($i >= $kolom)
           {
              echo "</tr><tr>";
              $i = 0;
           }          
           $i++;
           echo "<td align='center'><br><a href='detailBarang.php?ID=$data[ID]'><img src='$data[img]' width='200' height='150'/><br>$data[nama_produk]</a><br>
                   Rp. $data[harga_digit]<br> 
                   <input type='submit' name='ADD'".$data[ID]." id='ADD' value='Add to Cart'>
                   <input type='text' name='QTY'".$data[ID]." id='QTY' placeholder='Qty' /><br>
                   <input type='hidden' name='HARGA_ASLI'".$data[ID]." id='HARGA_ASLI' value='$data[harga]' /><br>
                   <input type='hidden' name='ID' id='ID'".$data[ID]." value='$data[ID]' />
                   <br></td>";


        }//end of while

  echo "<tr></table>";
  echo "</form>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Allan Sernal Dimaa Are u Sure Isset Inside the Looping?

Comment: Still not work Bro, I have try your code. My script has Blank